# separate part of a string into more strings

Tags: c++, fstream

I am using the function fscanf_s to make multiple strings from a string that I read from an .obj file. Perhaps I am misusing it i don´t know but I´ve tried with fscanf_s(file, "%s %s %s\n", &temp, &temp1, &temp2).

Here is an example:
f 1//1 14//1 13//1

What I want to do is to store 1//1, 14//1 and 13//1 into 3 separate strings.

I don´t really care for the fastest way to do it but it would be preferd obviously.

EDIT
For some reason ifstream >> operator didn´t work correctly in my project. I found a solution to my own problem though.

```
char s1[10];
char s2[10];
char s3[10];

int matches = fscanf_s(file, "%s %s %s", s1, sizeof(s1), s2, sizeof(s2), s3, sizeof(s3));
```

And then using the chars in string constructors.

Comment: Since these are space-separated items, just use a `std::ifstream` and the `>>` operator into a `std::string` variable.

Answer (score 0):

When using c++, I strongly recommend using the c++ functions as well :)
Try something like this for parsing your file:

```
std::ifstream file ("filename");
while (file)
{
  std::string token;
  file >> token;
  // process your token...
}
```

the >> operator extracts the next sequence of non-whitespace characters from an input stream (have a look: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/)